# VB with Excel About Range Use

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get the value from each cell from column A of the table compared to a value entered by the user, the problem is that in the line: 
    `If TamañoCmb.Value = Range("A" & Trim(fila)).Value Then`
The range value doesn't return any value when it should get the cell a2 in the first loop and enter the if.  I debugged the code and isn't returning any value.

```
  Private Sub CalcularBtn_Click()

    If NombreTxt.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Debe ingresar todos los datos"

    ElseIf TamañoCmb.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Debe ingresar todos los datos"

    ElseIf CantidadTxt.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Debe ingresar todos los datos"

    End If

    Worksheets("Información").Activate

    Dim fila As Single
    Dim Produccion_Principal As String
    Dim Precio_Principal As String

    For fila = 2 To 8

If TamañoCmb.Value = Range("A" & Trim(fila)).Value Then

            Produccion_Principal = Range("D" & Trim(fila)).Value
            Exit For

        End If

    Next

    ProduccionTxt.Value = Val(Produccion_Principal)

    For fila = 2 To 8

        If TamañoCmb.Value = Range("A" & Trim(fila)).Value Then

            Precio_Principal = Range("C" & Trim(fila)).Value
            Exit For

        End If

    Next

    PrecioUTxt.Text = Val(Precio_Principal) * CantidadTxt

    If Produccion_Principal < CantidadTxt.Value Then
        MsgBox "Producto primario mayor a producción, Cambie la cantidad"
    End If

    If Producto2Marco.Enabled Then

        Dim Produccion_Secundaria As String
        Dim Precio_Secundario As String

        For fila = 2 To 8

            If Producto2Cmb.Value = Range("A" & Trim(fila)).Value Then
                Produccion_Secundaria = Range("D" & Trim(fila)).Value
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

        If Producto2Cmb.Value = Range("A" & Trim(fila)).Value Then

            Precio_Secundario = Range("C" & Trim(fila)).Value

        End If

        PrecioSecTxt.Value = Val(Precio_Secundario)

        If Produccion_Secundaria < CantidadSecTxt.Value Then
            MsgBox "Producto secundario mayor a Producción, Cambie la cantidad"
        End If

    End If
```

Comment: you did not say which range is having the issue

Comment: refer to all your ranges like this `Worksheets("Información").Range("A" & Trim(fila)).Value`   .... or use `dim ws as worksheet` ... `set ws = Worksheets("Información")` ... `ws.Range("A" & Trim(fila)).Value`

Comment: Basically any of them are working because they always skips the if even when they're not supposed to. But if you want we can refer to the first range in the if, I suppose that if I fix that one all of them should work.

Comment: I tried both and nothing happend

Comment: the first two `for` loops can be rolled into one. just do both the assignments in the first loop

Comment: the indentation of your code is badly done. the program flow is unclear at a glance

Comment: Ohh yes thanks for that.. I'm debugging the code but the real issue is that the value of the range never returns anything. In the first loop of the for it's supposed to go in but it never does.

Comment: when working with ranges, and you are not sure if you are referring to the correct range, then use this `Range("A" & Trim(fila)).select` `stop` ... the code will stop and the range will be highlighted, so you can check if you are referencing a correct range ... the worksheet has to be active, otherwise the select method will fail ... you can use something like this also `Range("A" & Trim(fila)).interior.color = vbred`

Comment: That was of great help, the program breaks so I suposse that no range is being referred. Id that is correct what should I do to refer it well or what I'm doing wrong at referring it

Comment: It's of help to get to the root of the problem... but I don't really know what to do, I'm helping my brother with this code, it's my first time using vba so i'm a little confused with what is going wrong and what should I do, so I really appreciete any kind of help or progress

Comment: What I know is that the range is not referring the table on excel

Comment: i am going to spell it out then ... hinting does not work ... what happens when you add the `.select` code that i suggested and then run the program?

Comment: Shows a error message that says: error 1004, error defined by application or object

Comment: 1) Is it an actual Excel table? 2) What is the table name?

Comment: It's just the data it's not in a table format, obviously it's on excel

Comment: do this format then `Range("A" & Trim(fila)).interior.color = vbred` then look for a red cell

Comment: 1) Can you show an image of the data? 2) Can you give one line of the code that should be returning a value that isn't?

Comment: Kenneth, you should edit your question and include the following: (1) Which line of code is giving errors for you? (2) If the code produces some result, tell us what the result is and why it isn't the result you wanted. (3) Example data and/or a screenshot of what your table looks like. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information on how to ask a question that includes enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using a variable to store the value of the range like this:
`Dim celda As String
celda = Range("A" & Trim(fila)).Value`

Thanks to everyone for helpimg solve the issue!